# How can I get webpack to shut up about "Critical dependency: require function is used in a way..."?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webpack, browser

Getting rid of this warning is my immediate desire. Perhaps, however, what is needed is an entirely different strategy altogether.

I've created an npm library for various date/time functions. Nearly all of the code is general-purpose code that works for Node.js or a web browser. There's one feature, however, that requires some optional, platform-specific code: polling a remote URL for timezone updates. (The rules for when Daylight Saving Time begins and ends are constantly in flux around the world).

With a bit of ugly hacking I can make my code compile for both web and for Node, but there's still a webpack warning:

> Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted

Different variations I've tried simply result in different warnings related to `require`, or the code being `require`d.

I can suppress the warnings using `FilterWarningsPlugin`, but that only suppresses the warnings for me when I build my npm package. Any consumer of my package will still get this warning. If they suppress the warning using `FilterWarningsPlugin`, then any consumer of *their* code could still get the warning, etc.

Here's what I've got now:

```js
import { IZonePoller } from './i-zone-poller';

// The following crazy mess allows @tubular/time to be compiled for Node.js or for browsers
// without pulling in Node.js dependencies.
//
// eslint-disable-next-line no-new-func
const requestText: (url: string) => Promise<any> = new Function('require', `
  try {
    return require('by-request').requestText;
  }
  catch {
    return null;
  }
`)(require);

export const zonePollerNode: IZonePoller = {
  async getTimezones(url: string): Promise<{ [p: string]: string }> {
    if (!requestText) {
      const msg = 'npm package "by-request" should be installed to use zonePollerNode';
      console.error(msg);
      throw new Error(msg);
    }

    const zones = (await requestText(url)).replace(/^.*?=\s*/, '');

    return JSON.parse(zones);
  }
};
```

I've tried (and failed) to find some sneaky way to refer to `require` that webpack will ignore. webpack's "magic comments" don't appear to offer anything that will help.

One possible solution is to make an entirely separate npm package out of this one little bit of functionality, but that seems like overkill, and an awful reason to create a separate package.

Any brilliant ideas out there? Is there a platform-neutral technique, that won't cause browser CORS issues, to fetch web resources that I could use for Node and browsers?

Comment: Perhaps ["dynamic imports with webPack"](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/webpack-and-dynamic-imports-doing-it-right-72549ff49234) and in the webPack doc, you have [Code Splitting and Dynamic Imports](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/).

Comment: @jfriend00, I've tried those techniques and either they didn't work, or just caused different, more annoying problems. Maybe I just didn't use them right, but it's hard to be specific about what I have tried, because I've been all over the map by now, and it's hard for me to retrace my steps.

Comment: Well, webPack has specific features for code splitting and dynamic loading for different platforms and that seems like precisely what your need is.  My guess would be you weren't doing something right in what they support.  I think you're more likely to get help here if you follow their directions, post your implementaation and then post about exactly what went wrong when you were trying to implement it the "documented" way.

Comment: I have another couple of threads about the problems I was having with code splitting, and got no answers there either: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65444973/generate-single-module-with-webpack-with-optional-to-load-parts-of-the-same-mod, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65460402/how-do-i-access-a-dependent-umd-library-from-within-a-web-browser

Comment: @jfriend00, I finally did get a dynamic import to work, after deciding to ignore an error I'll detail below.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 2):

This approach using dynamic import finally worked for me:

```
import { IZonePoller } from './i-zone-poller';

let requestText: (url: string) => Promise<string>;

export const zonePollerNode: IZonePoller = {
  async getTimezones(url: string): Promise<{ [p: string]: string }> {
    if (!requestText) {
      try {
        // @ts-ignore
        requestText = (await import(/* webpackIgnore: true */ 'by-request')).requestText;
      }
      catch {}
    }

    if (!requestText) {
      const msg = 'npm package "by-request" should be installed to use zonePollerNode';
      console.error(msg);
      throw new Error(msg);
    }

    const zones = (await requestText(url)).replace(/^.*?=\s*/, '');

    return JSON.parse(zones);
  }
};
```

I didn't think this would work because the very first time I typed in `import(...` my editor quickly place a squiggly red line below the `import`, with this error message:

> TS1323: Dynamic imports are only supported when the '--module' flag is set to 'es2020', 'esnext', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', or 'umd'.

I wanted to leave the module format at ES2015, so this didn't seem like an option. And I didn't think `import()` was going to work when compiled for a browser target either.

But, lo and behold, simply ignoring the error with `// @ts-ignore` miraculously worked, along with the webpack "magic comment", to solve all of my compilation and warning-suppression desires.